# How can I give a UIImageView an animation which moves like floating on water, in loading splash screen?

Tags: ios, animation, launch-screen

I have googled this issue with all different kinds of keywords so far but unfortunately I couldn't find what I'm looking for..

In launchScreen.storyboard, I set a UIImageView in the center. I want this one to have an animation, which makes it as if it's floating on water.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xniW3_afO-0

Please take a look at the video above; the early part of the video shows what the animation should look like.

Does anyone have an idea to implement this kind of animation onto the loading screen? Or please let me know any keyword to find what I'm looking for. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this url may be it will useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112950/how-to-add-animation-to-launch-screen-in-ios-9-3-using-objective-c

Comment: This might point you in the right direction.  http://bl.ocks.org/brattonc/5e5ce9beee483220e2f6.