# How do you change the LaunchScreen Storyboard according to the country/region or default language of device?

Tags: ios, launch-screen

I am developing an iOS app. How can vary the Launch Screen according to the user's desired region or the default language of their device? I searched a lot but haven't found much to help me accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select project and add localization as below image

[image]

2. Add any language

[image]

3. Select desired storyboards

[image]

4. And here you can see storyboard for different languages.
   [image]

---------------------------------- Test your localization --------------------

1. Edit your target scheme

[image]

2. Change Application language as below images and then run your app

[image]

Comment: actually i did the the same thing but still no success :(

Comment: Have a look here :- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/TestingYourInternationalApp/TestingYourInternationalApp.html

Comment: hi.. i looked over there .. still no success

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't something you can do.

According to Apple's documentation on [Launch Screens](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/), the launch screen should not contain any branding or text, so therefore can't be localised:

> **Avoid including text on your launch screen.** Because launch screens are static, any displayed text won’t be localized.

If you want some localised text, you will have to present a custom view controller as your initial view controller as that will be localisable as any other view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  [See here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html)

> An iOS application should be internationalized and have a
>   language.lproj folder for each language it supports. In addition to
>   providing localized versions of your application’s custom resources,
>   ***you can also localize your launch images*** by placing files with the
>   same name in your language-specific project directories.

Comment: Your quote is about launch *images*, not a LaunchScreen storyboard.

Answer (score -2):

It's not possible.But you can mimic this scenario what just ankit said.
Keep the launch screen blank and **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** function create a view controller with region specific content.
Below thread might help you.This was basically to add animation and your's quest was region specific but logic is same though. :)

[how-to-add-animation-to-launch-screen-in-ios-9-3-using-objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112950/how-to-add-animation-to-launch-screen-in-ios-9-3-using-objective-c)