# How to make a animated splash screen from a gif in iOS Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, gif, splash-screen

I have to show a gif on my splash screen in an Xamarin Forms app. But i am really stuck, i don't know how to do it.
I have tried this: made my `LaunchScreen.storyboard` like frame 0 from my gif and then opening another screen to show the gif, but i didn't find a sollution to show the gif.

I have this class:
https://gist.github.com/jamesmontemagno/7619563

And this:
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/image_view/animate_an_imageview/

Comment: I don't think you can animate the real splash screen (at least not in iOS). What most people do (including me) make another page similar to the real splash and set this one as the MainPage in your App.cs class. In this Extended Splash View you set your animations. Once the animation is over or you have actually finished loading your app dependencies, you just navigate to the page you want/need.

Comment: Thank you @apineda but how can i do the animation everything i am trying is breaking :(

Comment: GIF is not supported in the launchScreen. refer to here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112950/how-to-add-animation-to-launch-screen-in-ios-9-3-using-objective-c