# React Native - fade splash screen into initial React View gracefully?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, splash-screen

Forgive me in advance for a question that may be construed as "asking for advice" instead of a purely technical problem. Knowing StackOverflow, the response may be swift and brutal.

I've just finished building out a cross platform (iOS and Android) app with React Native, and am in the last stages of preparing it for production. One of the tasks that needs to get done is splash screens.

Unfortunately, I have some pretty complicated design requests. I have an example app to work off called [Awair](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.bitfinder.awair&hl=en).

Here is the basic idea: the splash screen has a logo on it. The initial React  Native screen has the exact same logo on it, with the exact same dimensions, in the exact same placement.

The net effect is that the splash screen seamlessly fades into the actual running RN app. After that fade, we'll animate the logo upwards, etc (unrelated to this question).

Here's an example:

**Splash screen:**

[image]

**Initial React Screen:**

[image]

**Combined Effect:**

[image]

Obviously splash screens are almost entirely platform specific, and relatively annoying to set up. It seems to me that the hardest part of this functionality is ensuring the logo in the splash screen and the logo in the initial React screen are the same size, because one is controlled by RN abstractions and the other is a pure platform UI Image View.

Has anyone built anything like this in React Native? Any advice?

Comment: To ensure same size of both logos, why don't you set size based on the device's screen width/height dimensions?

Comment: @KetanMalhotra I'm not sure that's possible for iOS. Do you know for sure?

Comment: I know this for android & react, but not sure about iOS. My bad. I believe the above animation can be made within react-native itself, is the need for one of it to be a native view strict?

Comment: @KetanMalhotra The entire point is to have the animation "start" within a splash screen on both platforms. This is not a question of a simple RN animation.

Comment: @KetanMalhotra Thanks though, maybe you can post an example for Android and someone else can help with iOS.

Comment: I don't believe you can do any animations on the splash screen for iOS or the dismissing of it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112950/how-to-add-animation-to-launch-screen-in-ios-9-3-using-objective-c One thing I could suggest is having the splash screen be an image of the white square icon with the background image. Then when the splash screen dismisses you wouldn't actually notice the transition. The app would just open and when it began running your login animation would start.