# Is there any way to add some animation or any type of moving effect to an iOS launch screen?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am using this launchscreen code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="15702" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" launchScreen="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="01J-lp-oVM">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="15704"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="EHf-IW-A2E">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="01J-lp-oVM" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="Ze5-6b-2t3">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Test" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="EcF-nC-k2o">
                                <rect key="frame" x="137.5" y="309.5" width="100" height="48"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="40"/>
                                <color key="textColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.60084011130136983" green="0.0" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="EcF-nC-k2o" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="wza-7a-P1J" secondAttribute="centerX" id="4jn-PU-7OP"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="EcF-nC-k2o" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="wza-7a-P1J" secondAttribute="centerY" id="hft-du-2Xv"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="wza-7a-P1J"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="iYj-Kq-Ea1" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="53" y="375"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

What I would like to do is add some animation such as some moving dots or anything to show some movement this screen.

Is there a way this can be done?

Looking for any suggestions that people have experience in using.

Comment: You can't add any animation to launch screen. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37113278/10539446). Add an animation viewcontroller after launch screen.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.

From the Apple documentation

> A launch screen appears instantly when your app starts up and is
>   quickly replaced with the app's first screen, giving the impression
>   that your app is fast and responsive. The launch screen isn’t an
>   opportunity for artistic expression.

Meaning this that we as developer will not be able to add any animation to this screen.

Although, there is a "workaround". This is, creating an identical screen that will be the one your app will navigate to after the splash is dismissed. In this screen, you will be able to do all the animations you desire and once your animations are completed you can end by navigating to the other parts of your app.

Hope this helps.-

Answer (score 1):

What I do, is create a "fake splash" that is showed just after the real splash. For example my splash is a blank screen and when the app is loaded change to a page with a Lottie Animation, so that create the effect of animated splash.

[There is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYeRr.jpg)