# LaunchScreen.storyboard and Main.storyboard displaying differently (iOS 13 / Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, interface-builder

I've read that the way to [animate a launch screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37113278/6105256) in iOS13 and Swift 5 is to create a LaunchScreen.storyboard and Main.storyboard that are identical, and then animate the Main.storyboard elements when the view has loaded.

I have created a LaunchScreen.storyboard and Main.storyboard that I believe are identical - each consist of one image aligned to the centered of the superview. When I run the app, [I can visibly see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKolY.jpg) the difference when the storyboards transition from one to the other. Is there something I might be doing wrong here to create identical storyboards?

I have included screenshots of the storyboards that show the constraints I've applied to each respective UIImage on each storyboard. Is this the right approach to achieve an animation of the Launch Screen? Are there some inherit differences about the types of storyboards I'm working with here that I might be overlooking? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just a quick guess but, Instead of using safe area for constraints, can you try using superview?

Comment: @GüngörBasa I just double checked that - wasn't the case - I already have both constraints on superview.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue - I don't have a satisfying answer with a lot of closure, but essentially I just uninstalled the app from my simulator and rebuilt it and the issue was gone. Some previous version was being cached and hadn't been overwritten with the changes I introduced. Thank you for the folks to reached out to assist me.

Comment: Thats a common problem of iOS. It caches LaunchScreen and its really hard to get rid of that cache unfortunately. If you had a wrong constraints before it might have cached and that might be the reason.