# SwiftUI - How to make app don't show default LaunchScreen/ SplashScreen?

Tags: swiftui, splash-screen, program-entry-point

I am developing a SwiftUI app, there I added a custom splash screen, But now my app is showing 2 splash screens one is blank(the default one) and other is the one that I created.

How can I set the set App to Launch the App from my MainView.

In swift5, in storyboard view we can set this here [image]  How to achieve this same functionality in swiftUI?

**Actually I don't want to delete the splash permanently, I want to put my own custom splash displaying animated video without any video controllers.. e.g play, pause..etc.**

**Edit 1:** Adding Same behavior of SwiftUI

Below is the current behavior of SwiftUI: , it is not showing any option to select...

[image]

**Edit 2:** Adding Project Navigator Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Which `LifeCycle` do you use, `UIKit App Delegate` or `SwiftUI`?

Comment: SwiftUI lifecycle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, delete your unwanted launch screen inside the project navigator. Then:

1. Select your desired launch screen, then check "Use as Launch Screen" in the attributes inspector

[image: "Use as Launch Screen" is checked]

2. Make sure that the launch screen's sole view controller is the initial view controller

[image: "Is Initial View Controller" is checked]

3. > In swift5, in storyboard view we can set this here

It's the same for both UIKit and SwiftUI. To set the launch screen, just select it for "Launch Screen File."

[image: Project -> Targets -> Launch Screen File]

After creating a SwiftUI app with the App lifecycle, then following the above steps, here's my result:

[image: App launches with custom launch screen]

Comment: Thank you Aheze, but the issue is the step 3 that you mentioned is not only going to show in Swift UI 2.0 & XCode 12.5 ., updated the Question, please have a look...

Comment: @hafiza I'm also using SwiftUI 2.0 and Xcode 12.5, so that's weird... can you show a screenshot of your Project Navigator?

Comment: @hazifa I don’t see a .storyboard file... launch screens *need* to be .storyboards. You can’t set a mp4 as the launch screen.

Comment: I am not using .mp4 as a splash.. I want this video to be played on splash..

Comment: I am not using storyboard lifecycle, I'm using swiftUI lifecycle

Comment: @hafiza that's the problem... the launch screen is **static**. You can't play a video or run any code. It has to be composed of `Label`s, `UIImageView`s, or any other *static* element.

Comment: @hafiza even though you are using the SwiftUI lifecycle, the launch screen *has to be* a storyboard. Alternatively, you can use a [Plist Configuration](https://www.avanderlee.com/xcode/launch-screen/#h-using-a-plist-configuration), but this is even more limited (you can only add a image and a background).

Comment: Then aheze, kindly suggest me some solution, Android App is already developed with same UI. I want to play a video on Splash.. and if video is not possible then  some animation/ gif image... but the problem is we cannot set the splash screen timings..

Comment: @hafiza you'll need to fake it. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37112950/14351818

Comment: yeah, I think I've to do like this... Thank you for this much help.

Answer (score 2):

You can set this in `Info.plist` -> `Launch Screen`

[image]

Comment: I already tried removing Launch Screen from here also, it doesn't work.

Comment: @hafiza If you already deleted default Launch Screen, but it's still a problem, maybe clean build folder(cmd+shift+k) could help this. If the problem still occurs, I hope someone else could answer it.

Answer (score 1):

iOS does not allow users to remove the splash screen. This is for safety and cataloguing reasons. Removing it in `Info.plist` doesn't actually remove it for public users. Use the default arrangement instead of creating your own.

If you submit the app, it will be rejected without the use of a proper splash screen.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/28332

Comment: I don't want to delete the splash completely I want to put my own custom splash...

Answer (score 0):

in my case I wanted to use a custom Lottie animation and then move to my view, I created this view to host my splash and transition to my app's home screen when it's done playing

```swift
struct Splash<Splash: View, Content: View>: View {

    var splashDuration: CGFloat = <#Duration#>
    @State var showingSplash: Bool = true

    var splash: Splash
    var content: Content

    init(@ViewBuilder splash: () -> Splash,
         @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.splashDuration = splashDuration
        self.splash = splash()
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        if showingSplash {
            splash
                .onAppear { scheduleHideSplash() }
                .transition(.opacity.animation(.default))
        } else {
            content
                .transition(.opacity.animation(.default))
        }
    }

    func scheduleHideSplash() {
        DispatchQueue.main
            .asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + splashDuration) {
            showingSplash = false
        }
    }
}
```

### usage:

```swift
    Splash {
        SplashAnimationView()
    } content: {
        Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea()
    }
```

Comment: Does this show only the lottie animation? i am trying to do the same thing but background should be transparent while lottie is animating. so the home icons can be seen while animation is playing.

Comment: you could replace the if/else in Spash's body with a ZStack and have both